# Cycle between on/off states in javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets say I want a button to double in height when I click it, and then on the next click return to normal. So basically there is a onstate and an offstate and clicking this button just flips between them.

```
var button = document.getElementById("box1");
button.onclick = function() {
  ON: document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "200px";
  OFF: document.getElementById("box1").style.height = "100px";
}
```

How could I rewrite the function so that it keeps track of state? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your CSS:

```css
#box1 {
  height: 100px;
}

#box1.on {
  height: 200px;
}
```

In your JavaScript:

```
var button = document.getElementById("box1");

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  button.classList.toggle('on');
});
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById("box1");
    
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    button.classList.toggle('on');
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  height: 100px;
}
    
#box1.on {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button id="box1">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you! Follow up: is there a way to do it without just toggling a CSS class? Ideally I'd prefer to be adjusting the height of the element in JS (so I could apply an animation to it down the road).

Answer (score 2):

Add your new sizing to an `.enlarge` class:

```js
button.addEventListener( "click", function () {
    button.classList.toggle( "enlarge" );
});
```

The `classList` member is supported only in IE 10 and up, but [you can shim it easily](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations).

```js
var button = document.querySelector( "button" );

button.addEventListener( "click", function () {
   button.classList.toggle( "enlarge" );
});
```

```css
.enlarge {
  font-size: 200%;
}
```

```html
<button>Enlarge Me</button>
```